# For item attachments that represent a contact (.vcf), will there be a corresponding MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Per the docs, there are enums for .eml and .iCalendar item attachments. Will there be an enum for contact item attachments.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentcontent?view=office-js#content

Right now, item attachments that represent contacts have an .iCalendar enum.

Comment: This post is a little bit unclear. If you are attaching a .vcf file it will be returned as a base64 encoded string. If you are attaching an Outlook Contact into a message (as an Outlook Item) this is NOT supported. If you do  getAttachmentContentAsync on that type of contact you will get an error message. "The attachment type is not supported"

Comment: I dragged a contact into an email as an attachment in Outlook 2016 and when I view the email in OWA, these are the following properties.  

Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments[0].attachmentType : item

Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentContentAsync:   

format: iCalendar,   
attachmentContent: <Looks strangely like a calendar event>  

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Thanks for the detail, I did not realize you were viewing in the OWA client. I do not believe this is expected behavior, this scenario should not be supported.