# Discrepancy between attachment contentType and attachment names on different clients for item attachments

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

When using the officejs api (v1.8), we're observing differences between item attachment metadata when using different clients when looking at the same email.

**Outlook for Mac (v16.31 19111002)**
- AttachmentDetails.name properties include the file suffix. E.g. (fileName).(eml, ics, vcf)
- AttachmentDetails.contentType returns correctly (message/rfc822, text/calendar, text/directory)
- AttachmentContent.format incorrectly returns .eml for all item attachment types

**OWA (Chrome)**
- AttachmentDetails.name properties ***does not include*** the file suffix
- AttachmentDetails.contentType ***incorrectly*** returns undefined
- AttachmentContent.format returns .(eml,iCalendar) as expected for all item attachment types
- ***This ONLY happens when viewing emails with item attachments sent from Outlook Desktop on Windows.*** Example build (1911 12228.20332)

What is the expected behavior when reading attachment metadata on different clients?

In addition as per this prior [stackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840438/for-item-attachments-that-represent-a-contact-vcf-will-there-be-a-correspond?noredirect=1#comment100924119_56840438), are there any plans to support getAttachmentContentAsync with contact item attachments?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response, can you share with us which API and in which mail mode (Read/Compose) you are facing this issue? We see the contentType from Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments in Read Mode as well as Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentsAsync in Compose Mode return "text/calendar" for contentType, across clients. Is this API returning undefined for you in OWA?

Comment: This is for Read mode. The API being used is [Office.js v1.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-1.8#attachments). 

The AttachmentContent.format type was returned from using [getAttachmentContentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-1.8#getattachmentcontentasync-attachmentid--options--callback-) in read mode.